# Compare a date obtject created with integers

Tags: java

i have a task for school where i have to make a class Date to create a date without the java.time.LocalDate class but with integers for day, month and year. This date is then given to a class Employee and represents the date the employee started working in a company. Next to that i have to create another class in which the creationdate of that company is saved. In this class i have to compare the created date from my Date class with the creation date of the company. Can someone help me out on how to compare them? This is what i have in my class Date (didn't copied the toString, equals, hashcode and CompareTo

```
package be.vdab.util;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Datum implements IDatum, Comparable<Datum>, Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int dag, maand, jaar;

    public Datum(int dag, int maand, int jaar) throws DatumException {
        this.dag = dag;
        this.maand = maand;
        this.jaar = jaar;
        if (checkDatum(dag, maand, jaar))   {
        }
        else 
            throw new DatumException("Dit is geen geldige datum");
    }

    public int getDag() {
        return dag;
    }

    public int getMaand() {
        return maand;
    }

    public int getJaar() {
        return jaar;
    }

    public boolean checkDatum(int dag, int maand, int jaar) {
        if (jaar < 1583 || jaar > 4099 || maand < 1 || maand > 12 || dag < 1 || dag > 31)   {
            return false;
        }
        else 
            switch (maand)  {
            case 4 : 
            case 6 : 
            case 9 : 
            case 11 : 
                return (dag <= 30);
            case 2 : 
                return (dag <= 29 && isSchrikkeljaar(jaar) || dag <= 28 && ! isSchrikkeljaar(jaar));
            }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isSchrikkeljaar(int jaar)   {
        return (jaar % 4 == 0 && (!(jaar % 100 == 0) || jaar % 400 == 0));
    }
```

Comment: You can add a method compare() which will take a date as argument and return an integer. In this you can compare the dates and return a -ve value, +ve value or 0 according to the comparison.

Comment: When you say compare, is that to find out if they are equal? To check that the work start day is not before the company creation date? Or something else?

Comment: In a `compareTo` method (as specified by the `Comparable` interface), compare the years first. If they are different, return the difference. Next do similarly for the months. Finally, return the difference between the `dag` fields no matter if they are equal or not. If you get confused about which way to subtract, it’s always `this.someField - theOther.someField` (the other way around only if you want backward order).